# Exercise on Hilbert spaces and complete orthonormal systems

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space of finite dimension $N$. Prove that every complete orthonormal system in $H$ has $N$ elements and that $H$ is linearly isometric to $\mathbb{R}^N$.

I can't start with this problem. Have you some hints? Thanks

Comment: Once you have a complete orthonormal system that gives you the linear isometry.  So the part before the word "and" is where the work needs to get done. $\qquad$

Comment: You need to show that every orthonormal system is a linearly independent set of vectors.  And that if it fails to span the space, you can add another vector to it that is not only not a linear combination of it but is orthogonal to it. For that last part, Gram–Schmidt should do it. $\qquad$

Comment: A complete orthonormal system is a basis in finite dimensions.